# How to prevent Callkit from stopping AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, avaudioplayer

I have a voip video chat app using Twilio and I'm trying to play a ringback tone for the user making the outgoing call.  But whenever `didActivate:audioSession` is called, my AVAudioPlayer is stopped resulting in the ringback tone only playing for a moment.  How can I continue to play the ringback tone while Callkit has activated the audio session?  Here is my code:

```
func configure() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker])
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "Thirty")
        configuration.maximumCallGroups = 1
        configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
        configuration.supportsVideo = true
        configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]
        if let callKitIcon = UIImage(named: "callkitIcon") {
            configuration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(callKitIcon)
        }    
        callKitProvider = CXProvider(configuration: configuration)
        callKitProvider?.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ringbackMorningSong.mp3", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        ringbackAudioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        ringbackAudioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
        ringbackAudioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
    }
```

Then when a user taps "Make Call" button, ringbackAudioPlayer begins to play.

Then `CXStartCallAction` is performed.  Then `didActivate:audioSession` is called and this is where my ringback tone is stopped.

Comment: where are you calling ringbackAudioPlayer.play()

Comment: It's called on a different view controller when a user taps a "Make call" button.

Comment: experiencing the same issue above. Will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not best solution but I have fixed this by adding CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: callHandle) in participantDidConnect method (twilio). That way, AVAudioPlayer wont be interupted by CallKit, and you wont need AVAudioPlayer sound after other user is connected.